# Gluing two solid tori by a homeomorphism of their boundarries.

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

I am aware that we get all lens spaces by gluing two solid tori by their boundaries. My question is, do we get more spaces besides lens spaces? in other words, do all homeomorphisms of the boundaries give rise to a lens space or are there other possibilities?

Comment: You can only get lens spaces. 1) Classify homeomorphisms of the boundary. 2) See which ones extend over the solid torus. 3) After possibly multiplying by something that extends over the solid torus, get these into a simple standard form which you check glues the lens space $L(p,q)$.

Comment: In different language: these are the surgeries on the unknot. Saveliev's 3-manifolds book is a nice source.

Comment: Thank you! I will check it out!